# Trying to group by one property and get the count of entities in each group in core data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, count, group-by

I have an entity PackageHistories. I want to filter by myStore and group by myShoppingItem and get the count of each group.

My fetch request is coded below:

```
        let historyRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "PackageHistories")
        let storePredicate = NSComparisonPredicate(leftExpression: NSExpression(forKeyPath: "myStore"), rightExpression: NSExpression(forConstantValue: dataStack.currentReceipt.myStore), modifier: NSComparisonPredicateModifier.DirectPredicateModifier, type: NSPredicateOperatorType.EqualToPredicateOperatorType, options: NSComparisonPredicateOptions.NormalizedPredicateOption)
        historyRequest.predicate = storePredicate
        historyRequest.resultType = NSFetchRequestResultType.DictionaryResultType

        let itemDescription = NSExpressionDescription()
        itemDescription.name = "ShoppingItems"
        itemDescription.expression = NSExpression(forKeyPath: "myShoppingItem")
        itemDescription.expressionResultType = .ObjectIDAttributeType

        let countDescription = NSExpressionDescription()
        countDescription.name = "Popularity"
        countDescription.expression = NSExpression(format: "@count.myShoppingItem")
        countDescription.expressionResultType = .Integer32AttributeType

        historyRequest.propertiesToGroupBy = ["myShoppingItem"]
        historyRequest.propertiesToFetch = [itemDescription, countDescription]
        historyRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "Popularity", ascending: false)]
```

My problem is that I get a fatal error: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't generate select target token for expression: @count.myShoppingItem'`.

Did something change in the last few versions so that `countDescription.expression = NSExpression(format: "@count.myShoppingItem")` is no longer the right format? I'm using Xcode 7.2 and iOS 9.

Update:

```
countDescription.expression = NSExpression(forFunction: "count:", arguments: [itemDescription.expression!])
countDescription.expressionResultType = .Integer32AttributeType
```

doesn't crash, but it does give me gobbledygook. It doesn't return integers, it returns some kind of NSManagedObjectID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks OK. But should it not be `myShoppingItem.@count`?